# RESTLET - Angular.JS File Upload on Client Side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restlet

We are using Restlet for our API on the client side, everything server side is written in Laravel 5. We are having trouble in one portion. We have a couple endpoints that require you to upload a file. In Angular, I have only gotten that to work using the following method thus far:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image', $scope.file);
$http.post(apiURL + "/upload", fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
        }
}).then(function(response) {
        //yay it worked
}, function(response) {
        //try again
});
```

I don't know why that is the only way I have been successful, but I would like to change it over to the Restlet endpoint I have created. For most of my calls, it is as simple as this:

```
$rootScope.restlet.getCompanyAll().then(function(response) {
        $scope.companies = response.data;
});
```

and

```
var config = {
    params: {
        start: "2016-01-01",
        end: "2016-01-31"
    }
};
var id = 1;
$rootScope.restlet.getCompanyStatsCompany_id(id, config).then(function(response) {
        $scope.companies = response.data;
});
```

Pretty simple, but when I try to implement the post of an image, it doesn't recognize it, and leaves the image out completely. Here is the code I am attempting to use, it works with the non-Restlet way, but doesn't work with Restlet.

```
var config = {
    params: {
        name: $scope.newCompany.name,
        rep_id: $scope.newCompany.rep_id,
        image: $scope.image_input
    }
};
var id = 1;
$rootScope.restlet.postCompanyCreate(config).then(function(response) {
        $scope.companies = response.data;
});
```

Has anyone gotten something like this to work? And if so, how does it work? Thanks! :)

EDIT 1:

Here is the HTML of the page I have set up. It does have a file input, but for some reason it Restlet doesn't like the file. I have tried a plain file input, along with an input with a directive on it. The current version I am using is an image, that when clicked is linked to an file input that is hidden. I am also using a custom directive on it currently.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form ng-submit="createCompany()">
    <!-- OTHER FORM STUFF GOES HERE -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img src="" id="imagePreview" onClick="$('#imageUpload').trigger('click');" style="max-width: 100%;" />
                <input type="file" style="display: none;" id="imageUpload" file="file" />
            </div>
    <!-- FORM SUBMIT AND RESET BUTTONS HERE -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Custom Directive:

```
app.directive('file', function() {
        return {
                scope: {
                        file: '='
                },
                link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
                        el.bind('change', function(event) {
                                var file = event.target.files[0];
                                scope.file = file ? file : undefined;
                                scope.$apply();
                        });
                }
        };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your HTML but I assume that you are using an input with a type of file to specify the file to upload and binding to it with ng-model or some native Angular binding mechanism. I have no idea why, but Angular doesn't support this. There are 2 common ways to implement this.

The 1st is to use a directive that works around this issue. There's one here: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload.

The 2nd, and at least where I would start, is you can simply use document.getElementById to retrieve the file name from the input in your controller. IOW, `$scope.file = document.getElementById("myFileThingy").value`.

Comment: I have edited the question to include my HTML along with the custom directive I am currently using. Ignore the ugly spacing, Stack Overflow did something weird with the tabs.

Comment: I have not thought about using native JS though to grab the file. That would seem way to simple for Angular... then again... I am down for anything that will work.

Comment: Yeah, the document.getElementById method works pretty well. I've thought about creating a directive that just does that, but haven't gotten around to it.

Comment: I have a custom directive that pretty much does the same thing, but using `event.target.files[0]` to get the file and set it to the `$scope.file` variable. (or whatever you put in the `file="variablename"` section). The thing is that it works for native Angular, but not with the Restlet API for some reason.